# How to align a block of RichText/TextSpan?

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to align the block of text below so that it becomes centered. The current alignment is to the left. I've tried using textAlign.center, but this doesn't seem to work for RichText/TextSpan. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
  RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: <TextSpan>[
        const TextSpan(
            text:
                'Hello ',
      ),
        TextSpan(
            text: 'Click here',
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 13),
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
              
              }),
         const TextSpan(
            text: ' this is a test',
          ),
      ],
     ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `RichText` with `Center`

```dart
  Center(
    child: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
      children: <TextSpan>[
        const TextSpan(text: 'Hello '),
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Click here',
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 13),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {},
        ),
        const TextSpan(text: ' this is a test'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: That solution doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Are you using inside Column or Row?

Comment: Yes the code is within a Column

Comment: Then do same code like above and just add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` in `Column`